# Use idea to compile the geoserver source code, and the startup is abnormal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, geoserver

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-message       : Cannot invoke "org.geoserver.config.SettingsInfo.isUseHeadersProxyURL()" because the return value of "org.geoserver.config.impl.GeoServerInfoImpl.getSettings()" is null
class               : org.geoserver.config.impl.GeoServerInfoImpl
required-type       : org.geoserver.config.impl.GeoServerInfoImpl
converter-type      : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GeoServerInfoConverter
line number         : 21
version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1347)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.load(XStreamPersister.java:719)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.depersist(GeoServerLoader.java:1097)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.checkStoresOnStartup(GeoServerLoader.java:470)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:494)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:449)
    at org.geoserver.config.DefaultGeoServerLoader.loadCatalog(DefaultGeoServerLoader.java:37)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.postProcessBeforeInitializationCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:329)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.geoserver.config.SettingsInfo.isUseHeadersProxyURL()" because the return value of "org.geoserver.config.impl.GeoServerInfoImpl.getSettings()" is null
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GeoServerInfoConverter.doUnmarshal(XStreamPersister.java:2588)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 123 more
3月 08, 2023 11:28:35 上午 org.geoserver.web.Start main
严重: GeoServer startup complete in 4.642s
```

Comment: It seems there is an issue in your code or the library that you are using due to exception  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.geoserver.config.SettingsInfo.isUseHeadersProxyURL()" because the return value of "org.geoserver.config.impl.GeoServerInfoImpl.getSettings()"`. You could check/debug/search that related lines to investigate it.

Comment: post your code. then it is possble to find the problem.

Comment: Are you using java 11? Also it's possible that GeoServer is actually running at the end of that log, is it?

Comment: Java 17 is being used. It seems that Geoserver is not running properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. After replacing it with JDK1.8, the problem has been solved